# How to use Javascript to get ASP.NEt Web Forms label's value?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, label

I have the following label control:

```
<asp:Label ForeColor="DarkGreen" runat="server" ID="lblStatus"></asp:Label>
```

Its value is filled in the **Page_Load** event.

I attached the following Javascript (placed at the **end of the page**, not Master page):

```
function Validate() {
        var lblObj = document.getElementById('<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>');
        alert(lblObj.value);
        if (lblObj.value == "Replaced" || lblObj.value == 'Trashed' || lblObj.value == "Internal Use") {

            alert("Products with" + lblObj.value + "status cannot be reserved");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The **alert(lblObj.value)** displays a popup with text "undefined". How can I fix this problem? Please, I tried many combinations for placing the JavaScript but no luck! Thanks

UPDATE

Browser soruce code:

```
<span id="ctl00__main_lblStatus" style="color:DarkGreen;">Available</span></td>
```

First line of Validate JS function:

```
function Validate() {
        var lblObj = document.getElementById('ctl00__main_lblStatus');
```

Comment: you want to set or to get? question's title and content mismatch.

Comment: @Davide Piras, I meant get sorry

Comment: @CiccioMiami : can you port the result of validate function's first line by view source ?

Comment: @Davide Piras, see update. However if you want to laugh I just tried the script in IE and it works. It does not work on Firefox tough, I don't mind about IE

Comment: @CiccioMiami, use JQuery and will run in all browsers and platforms, something like: $("#" + Control.ClientId).next().text(); see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286317/jquery-getting-the-value-text-innerhtml-of-a-checkbox-in-an-asp-net-checkboxlist

Comment: @Davide Piras: if you put that as a (complete) answer instead of comment I will give you the green magic tick :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JQuery and it will run in all browsers and platforms, something like:

```
$('#<%= lblStatus.ClientID %>').next().text();
```

source: [JQuery: getting the value/text/innerHtml of a checkbox in an ASP.NET CheckBoxList control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286317/jquery-getting-the-value-text-innerhtml-of-a-checkbox-in-an-asp-net-checkboxlist)

Answer (score 5):

`label`s don't have a `value`. They have `innerHTML` and `innerText`.

Comment: @ Daniel A. White: I tried innerText and still gives me undefined

Comment: Is the client id being printed ok?

Comment: yes I already compared control and javascript code and they are the same

Comment: However if you want to laugh I just tried the script in IE and it works. It does not work on Firefox tough, I don't mind about IE

Answer (score 4):

Label server control renders as span. So you should get it's content by innerText. try this :

```
alert(lblObj.innerText);
```

Comment: However if you want to laugh I just tried the script in IE and it works. It does not work on Firefox tough, I don't mind about IE

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET label server control will be rendered in complex HTML output.
Like:

```
<span id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BodyPlaceHolder_lblLanguage0">
 <label class="inputText">English</label>
</span>
```

When you use getElementById you will get span.
But to set value via javascript you have to access inner label object

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getlabelvalue()
{
   var value1 = document.getElementById('<%=labelID.ClientID%>').value;
            if (value1.length < 1)
                value1 = 0;
}    
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you need to use the html method.

```
var g = $('#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').html();
```

These will NOT work with jquery:

- $('#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').innerText
- $('#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').innerHTML
- $('#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').val()