# Get Label text value into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rgraph

I am very new to javascript but unfortunately it is what I have to use for a thermometer chart that I'm using. I need to get the value of an ASP label text and then store that into a javascript variable which will be used to set the chart value.

For some reason it is not storing the value at all and the chart obviously doesn't have the value needed. Again I am extremely new to javascript so please be nice. :) Here is what I have so far.

Here is part of the ASPX page:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        // Create the Thermometer chart. The arguments are: the canvas ID, the minimum,
        // the maximum and the indicated value.

        var grossSales = $('#<%= MtdLBL.ClientID %>').next().text;
        var thermometer = new RGraph.Thermometer('salesThermometer', 0, 180000, parseInt(grossSales.valueOf))

        // Configure the thermometer chart to look as you want.
                    .Set('chart.gutter.left', 45)
                    .Set('chart.gutter.right', 45)
                    .Set('chart.colors', ['rgba(255,0,0,1)'])
                    .Set('chart.units.pre', '$')
        // Now call the .Draw() method to draw the chart.
                    .Draw();
    }
            </script>
<link href="Charts/RGraph/demos/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Charts/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Charts/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.thermometer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

And this is from the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["TeamID"] == null || Session["TeamID"] == "")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        //Populate department average
        double deptAvg = achievementData.DeptAverage();
        DeptAvgValueLBL.Text = deptAvg.ToString("P0");

        //Get sales data
        Sales getSalesData = new Sales();
        MtdLBL.Text = getSalesData.GrossSalesByTeam(Session["TeamID"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling .next() after getting the correct control in your JavaScript code?

Comment: I found a similiar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431464/how-to-use-javascript-to-get-asp-net-web-forms-labels-value. However when I remove the .next() it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var grossSales = $('#<%= MtdLBL.ClientID %>').text();
```

Note parentheses; `text` is a function, not a simple value. The `next()` is out of place unless you want the *following* control, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks a ton! That worked. `<script>
        window.onload = function () {
            // Create the Thermometer chart. The arguments are: the canvas ID, the minimum,
            // the maximum and the indicated value.

            var grossSales = $('#<%= MtdLBL.ClientID %>').text();
            var thermometer = new RGraph.Thermometer('salesThermometer', 0, 180000, parseInt(grossSales)).....`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `valueOf()` call in the thermometer variable definition line.  `valueOf` is used to return a primitive boolean. I'm assuming you're trying to use the grossSales number for something other than a boolean flag.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_boolean.asp

Also, as @catfood said, you don't need the `.next()`